Question about representations of $s l(2,\mathbb{C})$
I'm studying Griffiths and Harris Principles of Algebraic Geometry. In particular I'm studying the Lefschetz Decomposition of a Kahler Manifold (pag 118-126).
Before talking about Kahler manifolds, they study the representations of $s l(2,\mathbb{C})$.
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space, $gl(V)$ its algebra of endomorphisms.
Let $ 
\rho: s l(2,\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow g l(V),
$ a representations of $s l(2,\mathbb{C})$ (i.e. an Lie algebra morphism).
Let $X,Y,H \in s l(2,\mathbb{C})$
$$
X=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right), \quad H=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right), \quad Y=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right),
$$
and let $V_k$ the eigenspace of $V$ relative to $k$.
At page 120, they state without any proof that $$
(\operatorname{Ker} X) \cap V_k=\operatorname{Ker}\left(Y^{k+1}: V_k \rightarrow V_{-k-2}\right). $$
Why is that true?

This is clear from $X(V_k)=V_{k+2}$ and $Y(V_k)=V_{k-2}$, and $V=V_n\oplus V_{n-2}\oplus  \cdots \oplus V_{-n}$. By the way, it is page $120$, and not $123$.

@DietrichBurde could you please give me some more detail? I don't see it

@DietrichBurde Why do you suppose $V_{k+2}=0$? Do you mean $X(KerX \cap V_k)=0$? Is $X(KerX \cap V_k)$ equal to $V_{k+2}$?

My comment only was that if $V_k\subseteq \ker(X)$, then $X(V_k)=V_{k+2}=0$ and hence $V_{-k-2}=0$, so that $V_k\subseteq \ker(Y^{k+1})$, and vice versa. What is $\ker(X)$ in general?

@DietrichBurde Ok, I get that $V_k \subseteq Ker(X)$ implies $V_k \subseteq Ker(Y^{k+1})$. I don't see how this helps me with the original question.

You are close now. I will leave it to you.

Every finite representation of $sl(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a direct sum of representations $I_m$, where $I_m$ has dimension $m+1$, and $H$ has eigenvalues $m$, $m-2$, $\ldots$, $-m$.  Note that $X(Y)$ will take the $k$ eigenspace to a $k+2(-2)$ eigenspace ( or $0$ if out of bounds).
Now $Ker X \cap V_k$ will be the sum of $k$ $H$- eigenspaces in the subrepresentations of $V$ that are isomorphic  to $I_k$, that is another description.  Now it is also easy to see it is $Ker Y^{k+1} \cap V_k$.
It is best to see that any representation $V$ is a direct sum of $I_m$'s.  For $m< k$ we have $V_k \cap I_m = 0$.  If $m\ge k$ $V_k \cap I_m$ is $1$ dimensional if also $m\equiv k \mod 2$. Now if $m > k$, $m\equiv k \mod 2$,  then $X$ takes $V_k \cap I_m$ to $V_{k+2} \cap I_m$.  So the piece of the kernel is $0$ unless $m$ is exactly $k$.  So that's that.
